# Setting opacity to border changes the opacity of the inner contents

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, opacity

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="#AFAFAF" Opacity="0.1" BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBlock Opacity="1" Text="{Binding Story}" Margin="25 15 25 15" Style="{StaticResource content}" Width="600" Foreground="#636363" />
</Border>
```

I've even tried setting the opacity of the inner `TextBlock` to 1 to explicitly set it, yet the text still doesn't retain it's opacity.

[image]

See how the text is barely visible? How can I fix this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a Brush that's opaque instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your `Opacity` being set to 0.1 within you `Border`. The children inherit the [opacity setting from there parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx).

> Opacity is applied from parent elements on down the element tree to
>   child elements, but the visible effects of the nested opacity settings
>   aren't indicated in the property value of individual child elements.
>   For instance, if a list has a 50% (0.5) opacity and one of its list
>   items has its own opacity set to 20% (0.2), the net visible opacity
>   for that list item will be rendered as if it were 10% (0.1), but the
>   property value of the list item Opacity property would still be 0.2
>   when queried.

The easiest way around this is to remove the child/parent relationship and leverage a layout container such as a `Grid` to get the view you are looking for by mimicking the `Border` with a `Rectangle`.

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Green"/>
    <TextBlock Background="Red" Margin="8" Text="My Text" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The thing is, this border has to be dynamic as the text is never the same size. How do you suggest I approach this? I don't see how a Grid would help me.

Comment: @SergioTapia Just added code to give you an idea, the key is removing the `Border` from being the container for the `TextBlock` since the `Opacity` will roll down to the children.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to override the inherited property is to do something like : [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx)